# Python installation no longer working, reports that modules are not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, importerror

I may have completely screwed up my Python 2.7.3 installation. I have been able to setup and run Python 2.7.3 with all imports working fine.

But when I try to install python-dev, I get this:

```
ritwik@ritwik-pc:~$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 290 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,166 B of archives.
After this operation, 46.1 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package python-dev.
(Reading database ... 168442 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-dev_2.7.5-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-dev (2.7.5-5ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Setting up python-colorama (0.2.5-0.1ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 26, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref
ImportError: No module named time
dpkg: error processing package python-colorama (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-distlib (0.1.8-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 26, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref
ImportError: No module named time
dpkg: error processing package python-distlib (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-html5lib (0.999-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 26, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref
ImportError: No module named time
dpkg: error processing package python-html5lib (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-setuptools (3.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 26, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref
ImportError: No module named time
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: error processing package python-setuptools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-urllib3 (1.7.1-1build1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 26, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref
ImportError: No module named time
dpkg: error processing package python-urllib3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-dev (2.7.5-5ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-colorama
 python-distlib
 python-html5lib
 python-setuptools
 python-urllib3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Running `which python` gives `/usr/bin/python`
Running `python --version` gives Python2.7.3

UPDATE: `apt-get codeblocks installed codeblocks` (working, tested) but gave following errors :

```
ritwik@ritwik-pc:~$ sudo apt-get install codeblocks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  codeblocks-common libcodeblocks0 libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0
Suggested packages:
  libwxgtk2.8-dev wx-common codeblocks-contrib
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  codeblocks codeblocks-common libcodeblocks0 libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 290 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 8,574 kB of archives.
After this operation, 30.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libwxbase2.8-0 amd64 2.8.12.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2 [460 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libwxgtk2.8-0 amd64 2.8.12.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2 [2,371 kB]
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libcodeblocks0 amd64 13.12-3 [1,807 kB]
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe codeblocks-common all 13.12-3 [2,570 kB]
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe codeblocks amd64 13.12-3 [1,366 kB]
Fetched 8,574 kB in 2min 18s (62.0 kB/s)                                       
Selecting previously unselected package libwxbase2.8-0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 168449 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libwxbase2.8-0_2.8.12.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwxbase2.8-0:amd64 (2.8.12.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libwxgtk2.8-0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libwxgtk2.8-0_2.8.12.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwxgtk2.8-0:amd64 (2.8.12.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcodeblocks0.
Preparing to unpack .../libcodeblocks0_13.12-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcodeblocks0 (13.12-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package codeblocks-common.
Preparing to unpack .../codeblocks-common_13.12-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking codeblocks-common (13.12-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package codeblocks.
Preparing to unpack .../codeblocks_13.12-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking codeblocks (13.12-3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python-colorama (0.2.5-0.1ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 26, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref
ImportError: No module named time
dpkg: error processing package python-colorama (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-distlib (0.1.8-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 26, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref
ImportError: No module named time
dpkg: error processing package python-distlib (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-html5lib (0.999-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 26, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref
ImportError: No module named time
dpkg: error processing package python-html5lib (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-setuptools (3.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 26, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref
ImportError: No module named time
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: error processing package python-setuptools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-urllib3 (1.7.1-1build1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 26, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref
ImportError: No module named time
dpkg: error processing package python-urllib3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up libwxbase2.8-0:amd64 (2.8.12.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libwxgtk2.8-0:amd64 (2.8.12.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libcodeblocks0 (13.12-3) ...
Setting up codeblocks-common (13.12-3) ...
Setting up codeblocks (13.12-3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-colorama
 python-distlib
 python-html5lib
 python-setuptools
 python-urllib3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Do you get this same error if you run `python` from the command line and do `import time` at the REPL?

Comment: @Kevin import time works from command line

Comment: did you screw around with your system python?

Comment: I don't really know. I tried just too many things to fix the issue. Maybe I might have changed system python in the process

Comment: do you have any issues installing other packages with apt-get?

Comment: No, apt-get is working fine

Comment: is this in a virtualenv?

Comment: Its a fresh install on my laptop

Comment: Update : I tried installing codeblocks through apt-get install. Codeblocks works fine eventhough apt-get did return a few errors which were the same as those returned in the question. 
I have edited the question to include these errors.

Comment: To be honest something very similar happened to me once when I had an extra space with a rm -rf command , iI would backup and reinstall. It can be a nightmare otherwise

Comment: Reinstall ubuntu or python?

Comment: Ubuntu, once you screw the system python so much depends on it that it would take 20 times longer trying actually  fix whatever is broken if at all possible than to just reinstall and setup again

Comment: I suggest reinstalling Ubuntu as well. Make sure you run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y` first before installing `python-dev`. Also, might be a long shot, but try installing `build-essential` as well. Some may say it's not necessary, but I'm a superstitious programmer.

Comment: Okay then I'll reinstall Ubuntu. Could you also link me to a proper tutorial to install Python2.7.3 to prevent this again.

Comment: @RitwikGarg, it is installed by default. It is a vital part of the OS. Just type python into bash and you will have a python 2.7.3 shell. You don't need to install anything

Comment: `2.7.3` is installed, as Ubuntu needs this. This is often called the system Python, which **shouldn't** be modified. If you want to develop in Ubuntu using Python, I highly suggest using virtual environments. There are a lot of helpful tutorials online.

Comment: @Padriac I reinstalled ubuntu just now. I need python-pip package, can I directly install it through apt-get or should I setup python in a vurtual environment and then do the same

Comment: Thanks guys, everything works now.